# Retrieve XML node value using AutoHotKey and XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, autohotkey

I've been trying to read a node in an xml file generated from DSLR Remote Pro but couldn't get it right yet. It keeps returning an empty string. What I am trying to do is get the email address from the following xml.

email.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<breeze_systems_photobooth version="1.0">
<photo_information>
  <date>2011/02/24</date>
  <time>12:55:31</time>
  <user_data>test@domain.com</user_data>
  <photobooth_images_folder>C:\Program Files\BreezeSys\DSLR Remote Pro\PhotoboothImages\Masquerade_1</photobooth_images_folder>
  <photos>
    <photo image="1">IMG_0004.JPG</photo>
    <output>prints\20110224_125531.jpg</output>
  </photos>
</photo_information>
</breeze_systems_photobooth>
```

get_email.ahk

```
#Include xpath.ahk ; include functions (only required if it is not in your
standard library)   ; parsing
documents:  xml :=
xpath_load("email.xml") ; load an XML
document email := xpath(xml,"/breeze_systems_photobooth/photo_information/user_data/text()")
MsgBox, %email%
```

What am I missing here?

Note:
I am on WinXP, AutoHotKey v1.0.92.02 and XPath 3.14 from https://github.com/polyethene/autohotkey-scripts/raw/master/xpath.ahk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression is good.

Are you sure the file loads correctly?

---

EDIT: Can you try something like this?

```
xpath_load(xml, "email.xml")
email := xpath(xml,"/breeze_systems_photobooth/photo_information/user_data/text()")
```

Comment: It guess it loads correctly, tried it both using full path and filename only which is on the same folder as autohokey script. The thing is, it returns empty.

Comment: I don't know AutoHotkey unfortunately. See my edit up there, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: Thanks! Was referencing to the problematic documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was my XML file had comments in it and apparently xpath does not handle comments well.

Also it appears that xpath is no longer supported: [xpath no longer supported](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64844-solvedxpathahk-and-xpath-20-expressions/?p=409232)